# Codeigniter Count rows with distinct values

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

What I am trying to do is to group rows of a table by distinct values and then count the results while also relating the counts to the distinct values.

so I have a table like this:

id | member.id | value1  |  value2 | etc.

I need to count how many rows each member.id is associated with and return an array like below.

```
array(
  [member.id1] ['count'] => 'rowcount'
  [member.id2] ['count'] => 'rowcount'
   etc.
  )
```

I'm really stumped on how to do this using Codigniter's ActiveRecord and I don't want to run another db query in a foreach loop. Any help on what direction I should take would be most helpful.

Comment: I think I have it figured out, but it is requiring me to run a query inside a foreach loop.  Basically I am running a query to get the distinct member.id's then I run a foreach with that array and count the columns with the matching member.id and put those results into another array. It doesn't seem very elegant to me, but it works.

Comment: Whats your code for getting/counting the unique member id's?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try so:

```
$items = $this->db->select('id, COUNT(id) AS count', false)
                  ->from('table')
                  ->group_by('member.id')
                  ->get()->result();
```

Output - array of objects with id user and count.

Comment: That worked great. I just had to add the 'member.id' to the select statement to add that to the array and it does exactly what I needed. Thanks!